# Probability of Genetics Independently

Tags: probability

According to genetic theory, every plant of a particular species has a 25% chance of being red-flowering, independently of all other plants. Among 10 plants of this species, what is the chance that fewer than 4 are red-flowering?

n=10

p=0.25

k<4=3

using Binomial Calculator
http://www.vassarstats.net/textbook/ch5apx.html
=0.7759=77.59% Red Flowering???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s not the percentage that are red-flowering: it’s the probability that at most $3$ of the $10$ are red-flowering. And you’d expect it to be pretty high: on average $2.5$ of the $10$ will be red-flowering, and $3$ is a bit more than that.

If you’re still doubtful, though, you can work it all out by hand.

- The probability of getting no red-flowering plants among the $10$ is $$0.75^{10}\approx 0.05631\;.$$
- The probability of getting exactly one red-flowering plant among the $10$ is $$\binom{10}1\cdot0.25^1\cdot0.75^9\approx 0.18771\;.$$
- The probability of getting exactly two red-flowering plant among the $10$ is $$\binom{10}2\cdot0.25^2\cdot0.75^8\approx 0.28157\;.$$
- And the probability of getting exactly three red-flowering plant among the $10$ is $$\binom{10}3\cdot0.25^3\cdot0.75^7\approx 0.25028\;.$$

The total of these four numbers is about $0.77587$, which is therefore the approximate probability of getting fewer than $4$ red-flowering plants in your sample of $10$.

Comment: Thanks for genetics Probability explaining Clearly

Comment: @juniorgraduation2013: You’re welcome.